# ObservableCollection: managing events

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm, observablecollection

Working under MVVM pattern

`T` is a class, from my edmx file (entity framework).

`O` is an `ObservableCollection<T>`.

`O` is populated with all `T` from database.

Then, some fields of `T`, are edited by the user from the GUI.

How can I fire this event?

I don't want to edit my edmx file, I prefer to keep it like it was generated. So, this means I can't use something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/694370/How-to-Listen-to-Property-Chang), because I should modify my model, implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should interact with model objects from your EDMX directly in the view (GUI). Create a view-model to wrap your model class `T`, have your new view-model implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and use that in the `ObservableCollection`. Pass in the model object when creating your view-model. When a property is changed on the view-model, update the model object and fire off the `PropertyChanged` event (I'm using `YourEdmxClass` in place of `T` because `T` is often used with generics):

```
public class YourEdmxClassViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private YourEdmxClass model;

    public YourEdmxClassViewModel(YourEdmxClass model)
    {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public int SomeProperty
    {
        get { return this.model.SomeProperty; }

        set
        {
            this.model.SomeProperty = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.SomeProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool! Is there an example or a tutorial? Sorry, I'm new to this world! :)

Comment: I don't have one to hand, I'm afraid. It should be mentioned in any MVVM tutorial that deals with persistable model objects though, really - your view interacts with the view-model, and your view-model interacts with the model. Your view-model acts a middle-man - it makes the data from the model available for the view to present and change, and deals with validation and verification, among other things.

Comment: I get an error in the RaiseProperyChanged row, I think because this class doesn't implement the righh class.... solution?

Comment: You're in luck, I answered a question that deals with this exact issue a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25802912/718972

Comment: I don't get it... you say, in the other answer, to define the class like "public interface IRaisePropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged" but if it's already "public class ViewModelEdmx : TabImpianti", how can I do it?

Comment: Just add `IRaisePropertyChanged` to your view-model: `public class ViewModelEdmx : TabImpianti, IRaisePropertyChanged`

Comment: this: "ListaImpianti.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => EnableSave(e);" still doesn't fire with editing in textbox. I have done a wrapper like you write and ListaImpianti is now "new ObservableCollection<ViewModelEdmx>()" (viewmodeledmx is my new wrap class)

Comment: `CollectionChanged` won't fire when editing a property on a view-model in the collection - `PropertyChanged` on the view-model should fire.

Comment: now it works, I've binded propertychanged event of the single item to the event manager. FANTASTIC! Do you think this is a good way? Because now I have to write a long wrapper, for all classes in my edmx! :) what do you think?

Comment: Good, glad it's working. I think it's the best way. It is a bit of a nuisance that you need view-models for all of your EDMX objects, but the alternative, adding view-model code into your EDMX objects,  really isn't a good way to go. And as mentioned before, you can do validation and verification in your view-model, and abstract the data from the model further.